# Why is ELT more suitable for stream processing?

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

See https://youtu.be/2pgaQIitxiQ at 55.30 and then 55.50

It suggests that Extract load transform (ELT) is more suitable for batch processing at 55.30 and the stream processing at 55.50.

I understand that the idea is that as the stream data comes in we load it and then transform.

But in case of batch processing also, isn't it the same concept. The data comes in, we load it, then process as batch.

Comment: I think you have your acronyms backwards. ELT defeats the purpose of stream processing because you have to load the data before you can process it. Stream processing is literally ETL, with the (L)oad part actually being optional.

Comment: See https://youtu.be/2pgaQIitxiQ at 55.30 and then 55.50

Comment: I see your confusion .The presenter is contradicting themselves. They definitely got their acronym backwards. If you look at all the statements made from 55:50 onwards, they are talking about ETL for stream processing, not ELT. They just got their acronym wrong

Answer (score 0):

Historically, the target DB would not have the power/capabilities to effectively transform data and therefore a dedicated transformation server was used - so we'd extract data from the source, transform it using the dedicated server and load it into the target DB. (ETL)

As the capabilities of DB servers (especially with the rise of cloud DBs) have improved, the use of a dedicated transformation server is no longer needed - so we can load directly to the target DB and transform the data there. (ELT)

In relation to your specific question, whether it makes more sense to do (some or all) transformations in the stream or in the target DB depends on the type of transformation and the capabilities of the stream and DB systems. There is no right or wrong answer